# Using get_macro to obtain the value of a practice macro truncates the returned value

Tags: python, trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to control Trace32 from a python script, and I need to retrieve practice macros defined by a practice script executed at startup by Trace32. These macros contain file paths that define the location of Area and terminal logs. These paths are more than a 100 characters long. Calling `dbg.practice.get_macro` seems to truncate them to around 100 characters.

Has anyone experienced such limitations, or would know a setting to change this maximum length ?

RCL version used: 1.0.7

I tried the following code:

```py
import lauterbach.trace32.rcl as t32

dbg = t32.autoconnect()
# On T32 side, &MyMacro is set to C:/A/Very/Very/Long/File/Path/Of/More/Than/A/Hundred/Characters/That/Is/Being/Shortened/Down/To/100/Characters
macro = dbg.practice.get_macro("&MyMacro").value
# Obtains: C:/A/Very/Very/Long/File/Path/Of/More/Than/A/Hundred/Characters/That/Is/Being/Shortened/Down/To/100
print(macro)
```

Answer (score 0):

Contact support@lauterbach.com and ask for an TRACE32 update with build 162790 or larger.